# How to get latest salary of each associate in sql, table have month and year column also. each associate have minimum 4 to 5 records

Tags: sql-server

Here is my query

```
Select distinct ASSOCIATE_ID, 
                Rate_Billed, 
                Currency, 
                RateMultiplier, 
                UOM,
                MONTH, 
                YEAR= MAX(YEAR) over (partition by associate_id) 
from  asso_billinghrs
```

**Below is the sample data.**

```
|ASSOCIATE_ID   |Rate_Billed |  Currency|   RateMultiplier| UOM |MONTH|YEAR|
|---------------|------------|----------|-----------------|-----|-----|----|
|1              |23.78       |USD       |1                |B    |11   |2013|
|1              |23.78       |USD       |1                |B    |2    |2014|
|1              |23.78       |USD       |1                |B    |3    |2014|
|2              |1           |INR       |0.0146701        |C    |1    |2017|
|2              |1           |INR       |0.0147451        |C    |1    |2017|
```

**Below is the output**

```
|ASSOCIATE_ID|  Rate_Billed|Currency|RateMultiplier|UOM|MONTH|YEAR|
|------------|-------------|--------|--------------|---|-----|----| 
|1           |23.78        |USD     |1             |B  |3    |2014|
|2           |1            |INR     |0.0147451     |C  |1    |2017|
```

Get latest salary of each associate in sql table having month and year column also. Each associate have minimum 4 to 5 records
Thanks

Comment: can you add some sample data with the output you require.

Comment: already added, please see to it once.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
WITH CTE AS(
Select distinct ASSOCIATE_ID, 
       Rate_Billed, 
       Currency, 
       RateMultiplier, 
       UOM,
       MONTH, 
       YEAR,
       ROW_NUMBER()over (partition by associate_id ORDER BY [YEAR],[MONTH] DESC) RN
from asso_billinghrs)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: make it year desc, month desc:-).
Also, I wouldn't put distinct in your case. It would be unnecessary operation

Answer (score 0):

You may try using RANK() to get the following output.

```
 select * from 
(select *,RANK() over(partition by ASSOCIATE_ID order by tblyear desc,tblmonth desc,ratemultiplier desc)as r from asso_billinghrs)T
where r = 1
```

**Output:**

```
    |ASSOCIATE_ID|  Rate_Billed|Currency|RateMultiplier|UOM|MONTH|YEAR|
    |------------|-------------|--------|--------------|---|-----|----| 
    |1           |23.78        |USD     |1             |B  |3    |2014|
    |2           |1            |INR     |0.0147451     |C  |1    |2017|
```

[FIDDLE](http://rextester.com/JWYZ82193)

Comment: it gives right output for 90% data, but still giving wrong output for 10% data

Comment: as per the amount of information available the query should work fine, the 10% of output data that is not valid might have some other cases that you have not listed in the question.